# Get window from XEvent

Tags: c, x11, xlib

I'm struggling figuring out how to obtain the window a specific event was triggered from. What I want to achieve is the following:

1. Capture XCursorNotifyEvent
2. Figure out which window requested the cursor change
3. Replace the requested cursor with a custom cursor for that specific window

Step 1 works and step 3 would also work if I could figure out the actual window the cursor change was requested from.

Note that I do not want to change the cursor of my own application, it should work for any application. That's why I need to figure out which application/window requests a cursor change!

I know that every event has a window member variable, but apparently that window variable always returns the root window for me. According to the documentation, the window member does not represent the window that triggered the event so there must be another way.

```
XEvent xev;
Display* _display;
Window _root_window = XRootWindow(display, 0);
XFixesSelectCursorInput(_display, _root_window, XFixesDisplayCursorNotifyMask);

while(1) {
    XNextEvent(_display, &xev);
    XFixesCursorNotifyEvent xc_event = *(reinterpret_cast<XFixesCursorNotifyEvent*>(&xev));

    std::cout << "Window of captured event: " << xc_event.window << std::endl;

    ...
    XDefineCursor(_display, ???, MyCustomCursor);
}
```

Basically I need to figure out with what to replace the '???' in the XDefineCursor function call.

Comment: There is no such thing as "a window that requested the cursor change". A window doesn't issue a request to change the cursor.

Comment: The xlib documentation literally mentions the event window which  is "the window on which the event was generated" ( Source: https://x.org/releases/current/doc/libX11/libX11/libX11.html#Events ) and that's exactly what I need: The window on which the XCursorNotify event was generated. Don't know what you are trying to tell me, sir.

Comment: "Window on which the event was generated" is not the same thing as "window that requested an event" (there is no such thing, a window does not request anything). The manuals say "The window member is set to the window that is most useful to toolkit dispatchers." For some X11 events (key, button, ...) it is just the window passed to `XSelectInput`. For other events it is a special window to which the event is related, e.g. for `MapNotify` it's the window that was mapped. There is no such special window for a cursor change event, and it isn't clear what you expect it to be.

Comment: Alright,  thank you for clarifying. I appreciate it. You might have brought me a step closer to solving the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that my question was based on a misunderstanding (as you can read in the comments). To solve my issue, I have to query the focus window by using the XGetInputFocus library function.

```
Window focus_window;
int revert_to;
focus_window = XGetInputFocus(_display, &focus_window, &revert_to);
XDefineCursor(_display, focus_window, MyCustomCursor);
```

If you use this code, don't forget to handle possible errors.